# Attempted Ubuntu Minimal via Ubuntu Server + GNOME: VM Barely Responsive

Tags: server, gnome, virtualization, gnome-shell, ubuntu-minimal

In a VMware Player virtual machine (VM) on a Windows 10 host, I followed [a suggestion](https://blog.desdelinux.net/en/como-instalar-una-version-minima-de-ubuntu/#Instalacion_minima_de_GNOME) to achieve something like Ubuntu Minimal by installing Ubuntu Server 21.04 and then running a command to install the GNOME desktop. The recommended command was this:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

After a reboot, I have what looks like GNOME, but the desktop is sluggish to unresponsive. I was able to run `sudo apt install open-vm-tools` to verify that that package is installed and updated. (The VM has 2 processor cores and 4GB RAM assigned. VMware Player is working OK with other VMs.)

**My question: why is this Ubuntu installation nearly unresponsive?**

I wondered whether there was perhaps a problem with running Server in a VM, or a missing ingredient that such an installation would require.

Comment: Do you have enough graphics memory in the VM? GNOME desktop requires a lot of resources. Try `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xubuntu-desktop` in an identical VM, and check if it too is unresponsive. That can help decide if the issue is with GNOME or something else.

Comment: My choice would be `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-core^` to get MATE installed.